# Bootstrap Popover Not on Top

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm building a page using Boostrap and [Bootstrap Tiles](https://talkslab.github.io/metro-bootstrap/components.html). I'm trying to use Boostrap's Popover to show event data on a mini calendar. The problem is that the popover is hidden under the adjacent tile.

[image: Popover error]

I know `z-index` is relative to the parent and sibling elements but is there a way to configure the popover to be in front of all elements?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ok2zp8a8/)

Comment: Add the relevant code please or demo (even better).

Comment: I'll try and get a fiddle going

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the container to the body, like so:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({container: 'body'});
```

That makes the popovers parent the `<body>` element.
So if still needed, you can adjust the z-index from there.

HTH,
-Ted